# Magento 1.9 tax exemption for companies in the EU

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat, tax-calculation

A webstore located in Greece must follow the rules below for all products

a) All individuals with 24% VAT

b) All companies in Greece with 24% VAT

c) All the rest of companies in the EU with 0% VAT

d) Companies in the rest of the world with 24% VAT

All prices in products are included VAT 

How can this be possible automated in the checkout page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a built-in function for this called Tax Groups which you can access using the Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules menu.

Here is more information about setting up tax rules. https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-rules.html